# what is the airpush test_mode? true or false

Tags: android, airpush

what is the **test_mode** for banner ads in **Airpush** ads network, **false** or **true**?
I want to just test airpush ads in my app.

please help me.
Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name would suggest `test_mode` stands for ''enable testing mode" for your application. If you want to see how your application looks like with Airpush enabled, you set it to `true` if you are going to publish your application you set it to `false`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.... please tell me one another think, what is the  android:value="android*<Your ApiKey>"

Comment: if my apikey is 123456789 then param for android:value = "android*123456789"?

Comment: I don't know where you've got the *android* part from. But if this is what the documentation says, I should do it (since you can always change it lateron if required).

Comment: yes, documentation says that android:value="android*<Your ApiKey>" so, i confused about it. Thanks Mdlc.